# How can I remove small polygons left of a layer after using Erase tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, erase, natural-earth, species

I am new to more advanced use of ArcGIS Pro. My case involved cutting unnecessary parts of an IUCN range map of amphibians (I need only parts of ranges in Europe excluding Turkey and Eastern Russia). In order to do this, I downloaded a world map from Natural Earth and I have used the Erase tool to exclude countries and regions I was not interested in. The job looked relatively neat but I have noticed there are some little parts of the range layer that have not been excluded, which I believe they did not overlap with NaturalEarth country shapefile (areas especially around the coastline of countries). I hope the picture attached may represent my issue accurately. I believe the coordinate system is accurate. I will need to produce a species richness map on R with this shapefile and therefore I would like it to be as accurate as possible.

[image: Example of Turkish coastline with described issue]

Comment: Erase seems like the wrong tool here. Most of the issue is the lack of registration between the layers for coastline. If you take the country layer, select the countries, Dissolve that to make the study area, then Intersect or Union, you can use Delete to remove the features you don't want (and see them before taking the action)

Comment: Dear Vince, thank you for the prompt help! I have followed your instructions and, whereas the problem of the small polygons around coastlines is fixed, after I used Intersect I have now way more polygons in my study areas (Europe). Maybe I did something wrong when I used Dissolve for the country layer?

Comment: Update: I did solve that problem with tool Clip! Thank you for your guidance again!

Comment: Select by area, and the relation between area and length, copy features